# Event receiver will not change

Tags: 2007, event-handlers

I deployed an event receiver feature on a task list (it restricted access to the task for everyone except the assignee, among other things). Now the requirements changed, I commented out the permissions code, redeployed the feature and restarted IIS. Unfortunately, it looks like the old code is still running, and the permissions still get modified. Why would that happen? Do I need to deactivate and reactivate the feature, or delete and recreate the list, or maybe my whole site?

This is on a production machine, so I'm not really allowed to blindly test all my hypotheses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried manually copying the assembly to the GAC and doing another iisreset? Might be the least destructive way, and maybe the best if it's just a one-time thing.